# What are the differences between these inserts?

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

In SQL Server, these do the same thing essentially. What are the the pros/cons of doing it each way?

```
select * into table
```

vs.

```
insert into table select *
```

I'm looking for reasons such as performance, best practice, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT ... INTO mytable` creates a new table. It fails if `mytable` already exists.

`INSERT ... INTO mytable` inserts into an existing table. It fails if `mytable` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE
```

this inserts data into a new table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT *
```

copies the data from an existing table to another existing table